# PHP echo a comma between elements

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-table, echo

My code pulls certain elements from an html table and lists them:

```
foreach($html->find('tr[align=center]') as $e)
echo strip_tags($e->innertext) . '<br>';
```

The output looks like this:

```
OPEN 91212 ACCY 2001 12 Intro Financial Accounting 3.00 Zou, Y 1957 E B12 TR02:20PM - 03:35PM 01/13/14 - 04/28/14
```

Here is the HTML table these items are being pulled from:

```
 <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#006699">
    <tr align="center" class="tableRow1Font">
        <td width="7%">WAITLIST</td>
        <td width="5%">91630</td>
        <td width="11%">ACCY <A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~bulletin/ugrad/accy.html#2001" target="_blank">2001</A>
        </td>
        <td width="5%">10</td>
        <td width="16%">Intro Financial Accounting</td>
        <td width="6%">3.00</td>
        <td width="8%"> Zou, Y</td>
        <td width="8%"><A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~map/building.cfm?BLDG=DUQUES" target="_blank" >DUQUES</a> 251</td>
        <td width="13%">TR<br>09:35AM - 10:50AM</td>
        <td width="14%">
            01/13/14 - 04/28/14
        </td>
        <td width="7%">

        </td>
    </tr>
```

How could I change my code to echo a comma to separate each element? 
I want it to look like this:

```
OPEN, 91212, ACCY 2001, 12, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, 1957 E B12, TR02:20PM - 03:35PM, 01/13/14 - 04/28/14
```

Comment: Why not add a comma in the place where you added the `<br>` tag ?

Comment: He probably doesn't control the source of the table. And he's only looping through each tr, but wants all the td element's values to be comma separated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$html->find('tr[align=center] td')
```

Instead to loop through each td, and replace your br tag with a comma

Comment: This solves my issue completely. However, I have many of these of these tables. This puts the comma between each element, but how would I put the comma between each element AND break at the end of each line? Cheers!

Comment: loop twice. OUter loop going over all `<tr>`, inner loop going over all `td`s **inside the current tr**. Add comma inside the inner loop, add a `br` at the end (but inside) the outer loop.

Comment: Try messing around with it and if you can't figure it out ask another question regarding that

Answer (score 1):

```
echo strip_tags($e->innertext) . ', ';
```

Comment: If you don't want to have the trailing comma at the end, either collect all entries in a string first by concatenating to it instead of echo'ing the entries, or use output-buffering. Then use `substr` to trim the comma at the end.

Comment: No. Everything is returned in a line cause he is using his for each on every tr not td

Comment: @ElefantPhace Not sure if that's referring to this answer or my comment, but I don'T really see your point for either of those two possibilities...

Comment: @ElefantPhace Nevermind, looking at your answer I finally got it. ANd I have to agree.

Comment: For both actually. You're not looking at what all he have and what he is actually skiing

Comment: No it doesn't @Chitown you've misunderstood the  problem

Comment: @Chitowns24 YOur edit made it worse. Why use foreach if you want to have a variable counting up? ALthough it should get rid of the trailing `,`- the solution I suggested in the comment is much cleaner hwoever.

Comment: The problem is the trailing comma on the last element, this puts the comma in front unless it is the first entry...

Comment: I agree, I like your answer better. I was just typing mine while you answered

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('tr[align=center]') as $e){ 
     $str .= strip_tags($e->innertext). ",";
}
$str = trim($str, ",");//delete last ","
echo $str;
```

Comment: That will only echo the last `<tr>`. YOu maybe meant to write `$str.= ` ?

Comment: That won't change anything except add a comma to the end of that whole string he printed

Comment: Still not really correct, `=.` is invalid syntax. Plus you odn't define `$str` anywhere before appending to it, that won'T work either.

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. Why don't you test it and see